# Displaying all multindex labels in pandas dataframe as html

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Whenever multiline index is used, pandas merges same value indexes during export with `to_html`. I am looking for a solution to unmerge it or disable merging, so even if values are repeated in index, they are not merged
Currently pandas displays data as

[image]

Whereas I require it to be as

[image]

Comment: The labels are not really merged, this is just displayed this way for clarity

Comment: That is what I thought, but when I export it lets say with to_html() option it still exports it in merged format only which donot good for large dataset

Comment: I see, there is an option for that (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

When you export with [`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html), use the `sparsify=False` option:

```
df.to_html('output.html', sparsify=False)
```

> sparsify: bool, optional, default True
>
> Set to False for a DataFrame with a hierarchical index to print every multiindex key at each row.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in dataframe itself instead of when exporting

Comment: @App to my knowledge no, I am quite sure that the dataframe is fully unaware of this. Only the formatters/exporters are.

Comment: I am actually doing a audit using pandas and have applied style to mark mismatches and style object does not have sparsify option.